# Confusion on the Definition of Isolated Chord

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

An [isolated chord diagram](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/1T+relation) is usually defined to be a chord diagram with a chord that doesn't intersect any other chord. But in this [notes](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Elescop/preprints/LN668.pdf), it is defined to be a diagram with a chord that relates two consecutive points, so he has different (weaker) definition of 1T relation. Let $\mathcal A_n$ be the space of linear span of $n$-chord diagrams $\mathcal D_n$ modulo the 1T and 4T relations. (Kontsevich proved that $\mathcal A_n^*$ is isomorphic to the space of quotients of Vassiliev invariants $I_n/I_{n-1}$). Why do these two definitions give rise to equivalent $\mathcal A_n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from the fact that there is a well defined product on $\mathcal D_n/\langle 4T\rangle$.